# After fetch HTML from other page and append the script with "type='module'" it works just one time and then stops

Tags: javascript, fetch

I'm using "fetch" to load dynamically a html page content that has his own script, it works fine, but the pages need to have "script type='module'" since they import functions from other pages.
The thing is when the **type='module'** is set, it load the script just one time after that it stops to work.

Here is the complete code in the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fetch-html-with-script-bqikc?file=/index.html)

Anyway here is my structure folder

```
index.html
main.js

functions
 ┗ someFunc.js

pages
 ┣ home.html
 ┣ home.js
 ┣ page_1.html
 ┣ page_1.js
 ┣ page_2.html
 ┗ page_2.js
```

In the main.js I have the fetch function like this:

```js
//Event click of the main menu
let nav = document.querySelector("#main_nav");
nav.querySelectorAll("a").forEach((aElement) => {
  aElement.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    //Each element "a" have the attribute "data-path='name_of_file'"
    loadHTML(e.target.dataset.path);
  });
});

//Funciton that loads the content from other pages using "fetch"
function loadHTML(htmlPath) {
  fetch(`pages/${htmlPath}.html`)
    .then((res) => res.text())
    .then((html) => {
      let page_content = document.querySelector("#page_content");
      page_content.innerHTML = html;
      let script = document.createElement("script");
      script.src = `pages/${htmlPath}.js`;
      //set the type='module' in the script when the page is "page_1"
      if (htmlPath === "page_1") {
        script.type = "module";
      }
      page_content.appendChild(script);
    });
}
```

This is my main menu:

```html
    <nav id="main_nav">
      <li><a href="#" data-path="home">Home</a></li>
      <li></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-path="page_1">Page 1</a></li>
      <li></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-path="page_2">Page 2</a></li>
      <li></li>
    </nav>
```

Thanks to anyone who take the time.

Update...
I tried to use the dynamically import but it doesn't work either  [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fetch-html-with-script-dinamic-import-gt1n3?file=/pages/page_1.js:0-151)

```js
import("../functions/someFunc.js")
  .then((someFunc) => {
    someFunc.displayConsoleMSG("test");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Comment: You might consider loading the script via [dynamic `import()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#dynamic_imports). In either case, you'll need to define a function in your `.js` files that you call upon page switching, instead of relying on side-effects from loading the code.

Comment: @edemaine, I tried your suggestion but it dosen't work either, in the case I change the import code to this "import("../functions/someFunc.js")
  .then((someFunc) => { someFunc.displayConsoleMSG("teste");
  }).catch((err) => console.log(err));"
but the same problem continues, the page with the type='module' just execute the script one time and then stops, while the others script without type='module' works fine each time I call then with the menu.

Comment: I put the code in the codesandbox if you want to give a look [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fetch-html-with-script-dinamic-import-gt1n3?file=/index.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to replace the `<script>` tag creation with a call to [dynamic import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#dynamic_imports):

```js
      import(`./pages/${htmlPath}.js`).then((module) => {
        module.onload();
      });
```

For this to work, you'll need to define a function in your `.js` files (above, I've named it `onload`) that you call upon page switching, instead of relying on side-effects from the code loading process.

Here's a [working CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fetch-html-with-script-dinamic-import-forked-7y8vp?file=/main.js).